# Leetcode: Subtree of Another Tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree

My solution to the LeetCode's [Subtree of Another Tree](https://leetcode.com/problems/subtree-of-another-tree/) passes all the test cases, but the code feels and looks ugly. Would appreciate an advice on how to improve it.

The problem:

> Given two non-empty binary trees **s** and **t**, check whether tree **t** has exactly the same structure and node values with a subtree of **s**. A subtree of **s** is a tree consists of a node in **s** and all of this node's descendants. The tree **s** could also be considered as a subtree of itself.

Example:

> Given tree **s**:
>
> ```
>      3
>     / \
>    4   5
>   / \
>  1   2
> ```
>
> Given tree **t**:
>
> ```
>    4 
>   / \
>  1   2
> ```
>
> Return **true**, because **t** has the same structure and node values
>   with a subtree of **s**.

My solution:

```
class Solution {
private:
    bool isSame(TreeNode* root_s, TreeNode* t) {

        if (!root_s && !t) return true;
        if (root_s && !t) return false;
        if (!root_s && t) return false;

        if (root_s->val != t->val) return false;

        return isSame(root_s->left, t->left) &&
            isSame(root_s->right, t->right); 
    }

    void preorder (TreeNode* s, TreeNode* t, bool& is_subtree) {
        if (!s) return;

        if (s->val == t->val) {
            if (isSame(t,s)) {
                is_subtree = true;
                return;
            }
        }
        preorder (s->left, t, is_subtree);
        preorder (s->right, t, is_subtree);
    }

public:
    bool isSubtree(TreeNode* s, TreeNode* t) {

        bool is_subtree = false;
        preorder (s, t, is_subtree);

        return is_subtree;
    }
};
```

For context, here's the definition of `TreeNode` given by LeetCode:

```
struct TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;
    TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't look that ugly!  Here are some suggestions to make it better.  Note that LeetCode makes significantly more mistakes than you when it comes to code quality; I have listed the suggestions for LeetCode-provided stuff too, so that you don't make the same mistakes when you are writing real code — you don't have to force LeetCode to accept them (i.e., some of them can be compromised for the purpose of passing their tests).

## General design

The `Solution` class is very Java-style AFAIK, but it is not idiomatic in C++.  It should be replaced by a namespace, or removed altogether.  In C++, it is preferred to create a separate `Tree` class for the binary trees, instead of operating directly on the nodes.  Also, the value type should be a template parameter for reusability.

## Naming

In C++, functions and variables are generally named in `snake_case`, with `CamelCase` names reserved for classes.

The name of the function is misleading — to me, `isSubtree(s, t)` means "`s` is a subtree of `t`," rather than the reverse.  `contains_subtree` may be better.  The parameters `s` and `t` are also non-descriptive and thus unreadable; I recommend `tree` and `subtree`.

The parameters to `isSame` (or maybe just `same`), on the other hand, can be named as simply as `tree_a` and `tree_b`, because the semantics is unambiguous.

## Logic

(Note: the code snippets presented are intended to help you understand the review.  They are not tested; in other words, they and may contain mistakes and are not guaranteed to work.)

The logic of `same` can be simplified:

- if both arguments are non-null, then they are identical if and only if

  - their values are equal; and
  - their left subtrees are identical; and
  - their right subtrees are identical;
- otherwise, they are identical if and only if they are both null.

```
bool same(TreeNode* tree_a, TreeNode* tree_b)
{
    if (tree_a && tree_b) {
        return tree_a->val == tree_b->val
            && same(tree_a->left, tree_b->left)
            && same(tree_a->right, tree_b->right);
    } else {
        return !tree_a && !tree_b;
    }
}
```

This presents your logic in a way that is (hopefully) more readable.

Similarly,

- if `tree` is non-null, then `tree` contains `subtree` if and only if

  - `same(tree, subtree)`; or
  - `tree->left` contains `subtree`; or
  - `tree->right` contains `subtree`;
- otherwise, `tree` contains `subtree` if and only if `subtree` is null as well.

```
bool contains_subtree(TreeNode* tree, TreeNode* subtree)
{
    if (tree) {
        return same(tree, subtree)
            || contains_subtree(tree->left, subtree)
            || contains_subtree(tree->right, subtree);
    } else {
        return !subtree;
    }
}
```

This refactoring eliminates the unnatural non-local control flow (i.e., writing to the `bool&` argument instead of using the return value).  It also ensures that the function returns as soon as a match is found.